# open .gadget files with windows os again

Tags: windows-8-preview, desktop-gadget

To see the contents of a .gadget file I selected notepad on default program prompt after installing the .gadget.exe file (I don't know how I actually did it now).

But now everytime I open a .gadget file it opens with notepad. Gadget file's properties don't have open with button and when I right click the .gadget file its pop up menu also don't have "open with". I am on Windows 8 consumer preview.

Comment: You've got what's called a file association between .gadget files and notepad. Check out this link which should help, http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-change-file-associations-144102

Comment: what you should've done to see the contents of the file, was drag the icon of the file onto a notepad window.

Answer (score 1):

The final/RTM release of [Windows 8 doesn't have gadgets any more](http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/5/3138572/windows-8-desktop-gadgets-support).

Anyway, try entering the following command at the command prompt:

```
assoc .gadget=Windows.gadget
```

Answer (score 0):

First Off All .gadget is just an archive file so to see the content of .gadget file open with winrar,winzip or any compression software. next to change the default program right click and select properties.

click on change and set .gadget file as your choosen one application..

[image: .gadget properties dialog]